# C# application loading C++ dll exception

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

**C# application loading C++ dll:**

Got this exception:

**An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)**

Exception happens at

`CartToPol(fileName, _imageWidth, _imageHeight, _bytePerPixle);`

in following C# code (about at the middle, scroll down a little you can see the line)

C# code:

```
using System;
// many usings here omitted .......   

namespace CarPoolUI
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private int _imageWidth;
        private int _imageHeight;
        private int _bytePerPixle;
        private IntPtr _imageData;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();                  
        }

        [DllImport("D:\\Projects\\CarPool\\x64\\Debug\\CarPool.dll", EntryPoint = "CartToPol")]
        public static extern long CartToPol(string fileName, int imgWidth, int imgHeight, int bytePerPixel);


        public void ProcessData(bool doColor, string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
               string fileName = "D:\\myData\\data.dat";
            _imageWidth = 512;
            _imageHeight = 512;
            _bytePerPixle = 2;
                 **// this is where exceptions happen!!**
                CartToPol(fileName, _imageWidth, _imageHeight, _bytePerPixle);

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
               string err = ex.ToString();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

C++ (CPP) code:

```
// CarPool.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CarPool.h"

using namespace std;

namespace CarPool
{

    long CarPool::CartToPol(string fileName, long imgWidth, long imgHeight, long bytePerPixel)
    {
        long ret = 0;

       return ret;
    }

    long PolToCart(string fileName, long imgWidth, long imgHeight, long bytePerPixel)
    {
        long ret = 0;

       return ret;

    }    
}
```

C++ (.h) code

```
#include <string>


namespace CarPool
{
    // This class is exported from the CarPool.dll
    class CarPool
    {
    public: 
        // cartesian to polar
        long CartToPol(std::string fileName, long imgWidth, long imgHeight, long bytePerPixel);

  //polar to cartesian
        long PolToCart(std::string fileName, long imgWidth, long imgHeight, long bytePerPixel);


        //polar to cartesian
        static int* LoadData(std::string fileName, long imgWidth, long imgHeight, long bytePerPixel);
    };

}
```

An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

Comment: Nick, I'm fairly certain you can reduce the amount of code you posted to just the relevant bits. Please try.

Comment: Is your application a WPF application?  Changing a setting in IIS isn't going to affect a program that isn't going to affect a Non-ASP application.

Comment: OK. I will try to reduce the code quickly.

Comment: The appropriate action to take if you want a moderator to look into something, for future reference, is the “flag” button beneath your post or beside each comment. Inserting an obnoxious message in your question, funnily enough, makes it very unlikely that we’ll ever see it.

Comment: @minitech I've got your response, and well noted what you've been saying! Just as a side note (for the OP's concerns also): 1. I wasn't ever rude with my comments, just trying to drive the OP to improve his question (actual down & close votes seem to confirm this is necessary). 2. When looking over the profile of the OP, because I was just wondering, what's his usual behavior and quality of questions, I've been noticing equally bad asked questions, and downvoted these also. It wasn't really meant as _'revenge downvoting'_ (which I'm **really** experiencing all day long).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format error normally means you are trying to load a 32 bit DLL from 64 bit code or vise-vera.

Your C++ project appears to be built as 64 bit code (since your path to the DLL includes a X64 in it).  That woule likely mean that your C# application is running in 32 bit mode.   That is likely as well since as of Visual Studio 2010 client application projects (console, WinForms, WPF) default to a 32 bit target.

Check the project settings of your C# application by double-clicking on the Properties item in the Solution Explorer.  Then choose the "Build" section and ensure that the platform target is  "x64".  If it is "x86" that would mean that your C# code was running in 32 but mode.

Setting `Enable 32-Bit Applications` setting in IIS is incorrect for two reasons.  First your wanted your C# code to run in 64 bit mode, and enableing that setting would force the code to run in 32 bit mode.  Secondly that setting only affects applications running in IIS (read ASP.Net) not client applications.

Comment: It was check  on "Prefer 32-bit", but there is no x64 option. There are Allow unsafe code, and Optimize code, I checked both, and unchecked 32-bit option, it still fails the same way.

Comment: @NickXTsui - There is a combo box to the right of "Platform target" use that - there is a x64 option there.

Comment: I see. I found it, made the change, Now it seems it can find the dll.I think that is exactly the reason. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Given this line:

```
[DllImport("D:\\Projects\\CarPool\\x64\\Debug\\CarPool.dll", EntryPoint = "CartToPol")]
```

It appears that you are building a 64-bit DLL for p/invoke within your .net program.

My psychic powers suggest your .NET app is being compiled for 32-bit. Either compile both the DLL and App as 64-bit, or compile both as 32-bit.

Comment: I tried DllImport the 32 bit dll, it fails the same way.

Comment: @NickXTsui - Did you try "dumpbin /exports CarPool.dll" to validate that the CartToPol function is exported out?  (If you see name mangled garbage chars after the function export signature or a leading underscore, then you haven't exported the function correctly).

Comment: You are right, I upvoted you, but accept the downstairs as the answer.